# VBA - Public Array Error - Subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to declare a public array, create it and then use it in another sub.
This is exapmle of what I wrote:

```
Public array1() As String
```

---

```
Sub Create_Array()

Dim array1(1 To 4) As String

array1(1) = "1"
array1(2) = "2"
array1(3) = "A"
array1(4) = "B"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Show_Some_Index()

Dim a As String
a = array1(1)
MsgBox (a)

End Sub
```

I get Error 9: "Subscript out of range".
Couldn't find an answer, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `array1()` in `Sub Create_Array` is scoped to that procedure - basically it's a local variable that's only ever accessible within that procedure, and it happens to have the same name as another public field declared elsewhere, so what's happening is that `Show_Some_Index` is working off an array that hasn't been initialized yet.

`Dim` is used for *declaring* variables. If you mean to re-dimension an array that's in-scope, use the `ReDim` keyword.

---

A better approach would be to use a function that returns the array, instead of relying on global variables.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to declare a public array, create it and then use it in another sub.

In that case remove the `Dim` Statement from your code. Further to what Mat explained, here is another way to make your code work

**WAY 1**

```
Public array1(1 To 4) As String

Sub Create_Array()
    array1(1) = "1"
    array1(2) = "2"
    array1(3) = "A"
    array1(4) = "B"

    Show_Some_Index
End Sub

Sub Show_Some_Index()
    Dim a As String
    a = array1(1)
    MsgBox (a)
End Sub
```

**WAY 2**

```
Public array1(1 To 4) As String

Sub Create_Array()
    array1(1) = "1"
    array1(2) = "2"
    array1(3) = "A"
    array1(4) = "B"
End Sub

Sub Show_Some_Index()
    Create_Array

    Dim a As String
    a = array1(1)
    MsgBox (a)
End Sub
```

Once you initialize it, you should be able to use it in other procedures.